# how to render a view from controller1 into a view of controller2 yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm new to yii2 and looking for a little of help.

This is part of my `index.php` in the site controller (basic template yii2 `views/site/index.php`)

```
<?= $this->render('//tours/_form.php ') ?>
```

And I need to render the `tours/_form.php` (which is a view of tours controller) in this `index.php`

but the error is this:

> Undefined variable: model

I think the problem is in the siteController
but what should I add to it?

I understand how to render views that have the same controller, but I'm assuming that this maybe is different.

Thanks in advance for your help

Edit:

This my controller action from the site controller, this is just as gii generated it

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
```

maybe there I have to call the tour model?

Comment: show your controller action

Comment: @NitinP Added to the post

Comment: yes you need to call tour model and pass that model instance to your view page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your index action you are not returning any model, you must return the model which you wan to access on your view page,

**Note** you can return multiple models also

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model  = User::find()->where(['name' => 'CeBe'])->one(); // dummy example

        return $this->render('index', ['model'=>$model]); // this can be used on your index page
    }
```

model returned from your index action will be accessible on your view page
Please refer [Yii2 Controller guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html) to know more about action

Comment: glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have not passed `$model` variable to this partial view which is calling it. Do it like that:

```
<?= $this->render('//tours/_form.php', ['model' => $model) ?>
```

Of course for this to work there must be a `$model` variable to pass. It usually is passed from the controller to the view in the same manner.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = 1; // init the variable

    return $this->render('index', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

But you have to set this variable first.

Comment: Thanks! I added <?= $this->render('//tours/_form.php', ['model' => $model]) ?> but still getting the same error Undefined variable: model

Comment: Yes, you were right, I was missing the model in the site controller action, thanks for your help!